# AngularJs choose charts framework d3.js vs highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, highcharts

I need to add my projects few charts elements, 
i'm familiar with both d3.js and highcharts solutions,
I wonder which is more suitable for highcharts,
i came across few solutions uploaded to the web, but i'm not sure which one is better,
I guess i was hope d3.js and highcharts will support angularJS like they support JQuery, and they will offer suitable solution.

I want to know form you experience what do you think, what have you used in your projects?

does it make sense to user JQuery HighChart/D3 with AnguarJs?

Here are the links i found:

D3

https://github.com/EpiphanyMachine/d3AngularIntegration

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html

http://alexandros.resin.io/angular-d3-svg/

HighCharts

https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

Comment: This really depends on your project -- both are suitable and neither offers particular integration with AngularJS. I don't think there's a definitive answer here.

Comment: did you use one of them with angularJS? which one?

Comment: I haven't used either with AngularJS.

Comment: Note that d3 is only for modern browsers whereas HighCharts can fall back to VML for older versions of Internet Explorer > 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it does make sense to use AngularJS + jQuery + Highcharts/D3.

Longer anser: while I have no background with D3, I do use Highcharts on a daily basis in a large AngularJS application. I have found it to work seamlessly with AngularJS as long as a suitable directive is written.

The directive you found on GitHub looks promising, though writing your own (and perhaps a service to take care of the input data processing) shouldn't be problematic either.

Comment: so do you recommend using JQuery or using angular directive? did you implement the directive yourself or took it from github libraries?

Comment: I created the directive from scratch and used the jQuery version of the Highcharts plugin in it.